# Flutter animation not working for curve navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

the pages change when i click on the icon but the animation doesn't follow. for instance, when i click on the confirmation_num, it navigates to the page but the navigation bar is still at home page.when i tried changing it to other navigation bar, i keep getting assertion error. i just want the animation to be on par with the page changed

this is my code:

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rts_mvc_version_1/controllers/bottom_navigation_bar_controller.dart';

import '../../controllers/home_controller.dart';
import '../../models/home_model.dart';
import '../../models/user_repo_model.dart';
import '../../views/home_screen.dart';
import '../../views/ticket_screen.dart';
import '../service/api_client.dart';

class BottomNavigationBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final NavigationBarController controller;

BottomNavigationBarWidget({required this.controller});

@override
State\<BottomNavigationBarWidget\> createState() =\> \_BottomNavigationBarWidgetState();
}

class \_BottomNavigationBarWidgetState extends State\<BottomNavigationBarWidget\> {
int currentIndex = 2;

// Create instances of HomeModel, HomeController, UserRepository, and ApiClient
HomeModel homeModel = HomeModel();
HomeController homeController = HomeController(model, () =\> null);
UserRepository userRepository = UserRepository();
ApiClient apiClient = ApiClient();

static HomeModel get model =\> HomeModel();

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
widget.controller.setIndex(2);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CurvedNavigationBar(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
color: Color(0xFF273989),
animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
index: currentIndex, // Set the selected index to currentIndex

      onTap: (index) {
        //currentIndex = index;
        widget.controller.setIndex(index);
    
        setState(() {
          widget.controller.setIndex(index);
          currentIndex = index; // Update the currentIndex
        });
    
        if (index == 1) {
          // Navigate to the TicketScreen
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => TicketScreen(),
          ));
        }
    
        if (index == 2) {
          // Navigate to the HomeScreen
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(
                homeModel,
                homeController,
                userRepository,
                apiClient,
              )
          )
          );
        }
    
        print(index);
      },
      items: [
        Icon(
          Icons.notifications,
          color: widget.controller.selectedIndex == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.confirmation_num,
          color: widget.controller.selectedIndex == 1 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.home_filled,
          color: widget.controller.selectedIndex == 2 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.person,
          color: widget.controller.selectedIndex == 3 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.credit_card,
          color: widget.controller.selectedIndex == 4 ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
        ),
      ],
    );

}
}
```